# How can i loop a portion of this python code?

Tags: python, loops, input

this is my python script, i would like it to loop after an action has been done...
Here:

```
print("Booting System (Alfa V1.1)")
time.sleep(1)
print("Hello, and welcome to Training OS")
time.sleep(2)
print("What would you like to do ?")
time.sleep(1)
```

POINT1 HERE, The code should loop from here

```
txt = raw_input("1.File Explorer  2.System Info.  ( 1 or 2 )")
if txt=="1": 
    print("Loading File Explorer") 
    time.sleep(1)
    print("  _____    _____ \n /     |  /     | \n |     |  |     | \n |_____|  |_____| \n  File1    File2  ")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    file = raw_input("1.File1 2.File2 ( 1 or 2 )")
    if file=="1":
        print("\n\nFile1:"
              "\n_______________________________________"
              "\nTOP SECRET UPDATE INFO:"
              "\n           Update Name . . . . 1.2"
              "\nEstimated Release Date . . . . 25.09.21"
              "\n           New Features . . . . Games?"
              "\n_______________________________________")
```

Loop to POINT1 once this is executed

```
    else:
        print("\n\nFile2:"
              "\n----------------------------------------"
              "\n                                        "
              "\n              Error 404.                "
              "\n             File Missing               "
              "\n                                        "
              "\n----------------------------------------")
```

Loop to POINT1 once this is executed

```
else:
    print("\n\nSystem Info:"
          "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
          "\n\nOs version: . . . . . 1.1 (New features: File Explorer)"
          "\n   Founded: . . . . . 22.09.2021, Baku, Azerbaijan"
          "\n  Products: . . . . . TOS"
          "\n\n***This OS is still being developed so some features are currently unaviable :(***"
          "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
```

Loop to POINT1 once this is executed

NOTE THAT THE 4 SEPARATED CODE PART FOLLOW EACH OTHER IN ONE PIECE

It would be so cool if someone actually managed to help me, i just started learning python and i really would like to finish this project :)

Comment: As an aside, it looks like you are using python 2 which is at end-of-life. `raw_input` changed to just `input` in python 3.

Answer (score 2):

`while` and `for` loops in python are what you need.

The syntax of `while` is as follows:

```py
while condition:
    # This section will continue to execute until the condition declared above is False.
    do_something()
    some_var = "Value"
    do_something_crazy(some_var)

# This section will be executed after the loop has finished.
print("Wow very cool!")
```

As long as the condition is met (*while* the condition evaluates to True), the loop will continue to execute.

The `for` loop is a bit different. It doesn't require a condition, but rather a sequence, a collection of sort to enumerate and iterate through.

The syntax of `for` is as follows:

```py
for variable in collection:
    # This section will execute the for each item in the collection. In each iteration the value of `variable` will be of the current item in the collection.
    do_something_with(variable)
    print(variable, "is very cool")

# This section will execute after the last item in the collection.
print("These are all the items")

# Example:
cool_dogs = ["Shiba Inu", "Bulldog", "Pitbull"]

for dog in cool_dogs:
    print("This dog is one of my favorites: ", dog)

print("I love dogs!")
```

Using this new knowledge, you can now use loops where you want and need them in your code.

Comment: Thanks, i will read this again a few times to understand the code and how to use it in my script, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a while loop.

You will need to put the function that need to put in that loop, separate from the main process of the script.

```py
def ask_or_something():
    txt = raw_input("1.File Explorer  2.System Info.  ( 1 or 2 )")
    if txt == "1":
        print("Loading File Explorer")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("  _____    _____ \n /     |  /     | \n |     |  |     | \n |_____|  |_____| \n  File1    File2  ")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        file = raw_input("1.File1 2.File2 ( 1 or 2 )")
        if file == "1":
            print("\n\nFile1:"
                  "\n_______________________________________"
                  "\nTOP SECRET UPDATE INFO:"
                  "\n           Update Name . . . . 1.2"
                  "\nEstimated Release Date . . . . 25.09.21"
                  "\n           New Features . . . . Games?"
                  "\n_______________________________________")

        else:
            print("\n\nFile2:"
                  "\n----------------------------------------"
                  "\n                                        "
                  "\n              Error 404.                "
                  "\n             File Missing               "
                  "\n                                        "
                  "\n----------------------------------------")

    else:
        print("\n\nSystem Info:"
              "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
              "\n\nOs version: . . . . . 1.1 (New features: File Explorer)"
              "\n   Founded: . . . . . 22.09.2021, Baku, Azerbaijan"
              "\n  Products: . . . . . TOS"
              "\n\n***This OS is still being developed so some features are currently unaviable :(***"
              "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        
# need a main process to control all the loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        ask_or_something()
```